# Mouseover on dropdown showing tooltip of the selected text

Tags: jquery

I have 5 dropdown lists and I want to have a tooltip on each of them such that when a user hovers their mouse over any dropdown list, there is a tooltip that appears to show the selected text.

```
<select name="dropdn" class="mydpdn">
    <option>Loading...</option>
</select>
```

I am trying to use `jquery.dimensions.js` and `jquery.tooltip.js`.  Can anyone give me an example please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this might work:

```
$("select").tooltip({
    left: 25,
    bodyHandler: function(){
        return $('.mydpdn').attr('title');
    }
});

$('.mydpdn').bind('change', function(e){
    var newTitle='';
    $(".mydpdn option:selected").each(function () {
        newTitle+= $(this).text() + " ";
    });
    $(this).attr('title', newTitle);
});

$('.mydpdn').trigger('change');
```

Hope it helps

Comment: thanks, I have tested it, it seems that all the dropdown tooltips are showing all the dropdown selected texts. It should be showing the selected text of that particular dropdown were the mouse is pointing.